# Calculate if today date between 2 other dates - But only with day and month

Tags: java, date

I'm in a weird situation,
I want to calculate if a date is between 2 other date, but only with day and month.

Example (with dd/mm) :

- today date : 17/01
- FirstInterval : 01/11
- SecondInterval : 19/01

Should be TRUE.

And this example :

- today date : 17/01
- FirstInterval : 06/06
- SecondInterval : 08/08

Should be FALSE

Is there a simple method to deal with this ? I don't really know how to deal with years with those dates.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the java.time package and classes such as LocalDate and methods such as [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-)

Comment: @f1sh, yes that's what I'm using, but my issue is more with year for example when the second month is in the next year

Comment: @Cesar There is no “next year” when dealing with month-day.

Comment: The best way to do a season-check is by splitting the period at Newyear. Then you simply set all year numbers to 2000 and check if the date is within one of both ranges. EG winter (2022/12/21 - 2023/03/20) - year numbers are different so we split it - (2000/12/21 - 2000/12/31 and 2000/01/01 - 2000/03/20) - Now check if Christmas 2000/12/25 is within one of these ranges. Example code [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/blob/master/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/SeasonChecker.cs#L87-L124)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats one way of doing it:

```
boolean isDateBetween(String dateToTest, String lowerDate, String upperDate) {
    int anyYear = 2000;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse(lowerDate + "/" + anyYear, formatter);
    LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse(upperDate + "/" + anyYear, formatter);
    if (d2.isBefore(d1)) {
      d1 = d1.minusYears(1);
    }
    LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.parse(dateToTest + "/" + anyYear, formatter);
    return testDate.isEqual(d1) || testDate.isAfter(d1) && (testDate.isEqual(d2) || testDate.isBefore(d2));
  }
```

Test:

```
    boolean result1 = isDateBetween("17/01", "01/11", "19/01");
    boolean result2 = isDateBetween("17/01", "06/06", "07/08");
    System.out.println(result1);
    System.out.println(result2);
```

Prints:

```
true
false
```

Haven't tested it properly, but it should work.

Comment: As I understood the problem, OP wants to compare dates ignoring year. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: If so then you could add line that when `d2.isBefore(d1)` then `d2 = d2.plusYears(1)`, but that sounds very flimsy.

Comment: Ok. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: It does work, with this method, it's smart to minus a year to the firstdate instead of adding one to the second ...
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Use the `java.time.MonthDay` class to represent the *dates*. It has methods like `isAfter()`, `isBefore()` and `compareTo()` to compare two instances.
One problem is handling the case when the period covers a year change, that is, when the start date is after the end date.

```java
    boolean checkInterval(String testDate, String startDate, String endDate) {
        var format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM");
        var test = MonthDay.parse(testDate, format);
        var start = MonthDay.parse(startDate, format);
        var end = MonthDay.parse(endDate, format);

        if (end.isBefore(start)) {
            // end must be in *next* year
            return !(test.isBefore(start) && test.isAfter(end));
        } else {
            // start and end on same year
            return !(test.isBefore(start) || test.isAfter(end));
        }
    }
```

Since `isAfter()` and `isBefore()` returns false if the `MonthDay`s are equal, the code is using `! isAfter()` instead of `isBefore()` and vice-versa. (`! isAfter()` will return `true` if the `MonthDay`s are equal or if the first (`this`) is **before** the argument - mathematically `x >= y` is the same as `not(x < y)`)

Answer (score 1):

When the year is omitted, the maximum span between `FirstInterval` and `SecondInterval` is 12 month.

The samples are using day/month combinations that allows the assumption that all dates are in the same year. This means that the `FirstInterval` may never be greater than `SecondInterval`, otherwise the end of the period must be in the following year.

But in that case, it is impossible to determine whether the `todayDate` fits into the period because it may belong to "this" year or to the "following" year (and we don't know which is right).

So to be able to get a deterministic output, we have to assume that all three dates are for the same year.

A solution may look like this:

```
public final boolean isDateBetween( final String todayDate, final String firstInterval, final String secondInterval ) 
{
  var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM");
  var lowerRange = MonthDay.parse( firstInterval, formatter );
  var upperRange = MonthDay.parse( secondInterval, formatter );
  if( !upperRange.isAfter( lowerRange ) ) throw new Error();
  var testDate = MonthDay.parse( todayDate, formatter );

  var retValue = !testDate.isBefore( lowerRange ) && !testDate.isAfter( upperRange );

  return retValue;
}
```

Of course, a proper error handling is missing here and needs to be added.

But let's assume that the time range has a meaning like "Season of the Year", and we want to know if a `todayDate` is in Winter or not.

Such a solution may look like this:

```
public final boolean isDayInSeason( final String today, final String begin, final String end ) 
{
  boolean retValue = false;
  var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM");
  var lowerRange = MonthDay.parse( begin, formatter );
  var upperRange = MonthDay.parse( end, formatter );
  if( !upperRange.isAfter( lowerRange ) )
  {
     retValue = isDayInSeason( today, lowerRange, "31/12" ) || isDayInSeason( today, "01/01", upperRange );
  }
  else
  {
     var testDate = MonthDay.parse( todayDate, formatter );
     retValue = !testDate.isBefore( lowerRange ) && !testDate.isAfter( upperRange );
  }
  return retValue;
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 – You read my answer to full extent? No, I assume … For your sample: is Dec 12th in the range, or not? Without the year, the answer is Yo or Nes – you cannot say it for sure. So my answer is based on the on the current definition of the input data the only proper one, for a computer program. Your sample is for humans …

Comment: @user16320675 – Specifications are made by humans, and samples are no specifications. That Dec 12 is in that range is because you gave that range a meaning that is not available to a computer, and not mentioned in the "specification", it is just an assumption made by you.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the day and month of the 3 dates into 6 variables such as:
dd1, mm1, dd2, mm2, dd3 and mm3.

Once you have those numbers, do a simple number comparison in an if statement.